# Products and different types of products

Tags: database, database-design

How would I draw up this design in a database?

- A product can be physical, digital, or a service.
- A digital product is a product.
- A physical product is a product.
- A service is a product.

Would it be advisable to use a different unique identifier than just an auto-incremented id?  Perhaps a hash of the `id` and some other identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto incremented id's will work fine.  I'd recommend a separate table for types, in case you want to add more in the future.

```
Product
id  type_id  name
1   2        candy
2   2        car
3   3        yard work

Type
id  name
1   digital
2   physical
3   service
```

Comment: This seems like a better solution than having 3 separate tables for `physical`, `service, and `digital`.